# At the time of update my where condition is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

In my first `table(ts_users)` update opening `user_opening_balance` at the same time, I want to update that `user_opening_balance` in my second `table(ts_voucher)` column is `voucher_amount`. But in my second table `table(ts_voucher)`  `voucher_amount` updates all columns amount.

My code:

```
public function updateConsignor($myData){
      extract($myData);

      $this->db->set('user_full_name' , $user_full_name);
      $this->db->set('user_opening_balance' , $user_opening_balance);

    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

      if($this->db->update('ts_users')){

         $userId      = $myData['user_id'];
          $this->db->trans_begin();
                                $openingBalTrxn = array(
                                'voucher_amount'               => $myData['user_opening_balance'],
                                );

          $this->db->update('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);
          $this->db->where('voucher_person_account_id',$userId);

            if ($this->db->trans_status() === false){
                      $this->db->trans_rollback();
                      return false;
             }else{
                      $this->db->trans_commit();
                      return true;
                  }

           return $query_result;

           return true;
      }else{

        return false;
      }

    }
```

I am giving where condition

```
$this->db->update('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);
$this->db->where('voucher_person_account_id',$userId);
```

for update one record it updates all `voucher_amount` column record

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run first your `.where` before your `.update`. See documentation [here](https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-active-record.html#6)

```
$this->db->where('voucher_person_account_id',$userId);
$this->db->update('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your update query false. where clause first and other condition where first than update function call just copy this function and fix your problem.

```
public function updateConsignor($myData){
  extract($myData);

  $this->db->set('user_full_name' , $user_full_name);
  $this->db->set('user_opening_balance' , $user_opening_balance);

$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

  if($this->db->update('ts_users')){

     $userId      = $myData['user_id'];
      $this->db->trans_begin();
                            $openingBalTrxn = array(
                            'voucher_amount'               => $myData['user_opening_balance'],
                            );
      $this->db->where('voucher_person_account_id',$userId);
      $this->db->update('ts_voucher', $openingBalTrxn);

         if ($this->db->trans_status() === false){
                  $this->db->trans_rollback();
                  return false;
         }else{
                  $this->db->trans_commit();
                  return true;
              }

       return $query_result;

       return true;
  }else{

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: codeigniter update query here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 1):

Your update operation is working before the 'where' condition has a chance to work. That's why it's updating all records. Simply put the where condition first, then update.